# How can I persist the analysis result for an NDepend project?

Tags: code-analysis, ndepend

I am trying out NDepend (2018.2.0) but I am stuck early with this one and I am receiving an error for reasons that don't appear to be true.

After install NDepend and starting VS 2015:

1. Add Assemblies From VS Solution
2. I select the sln file
3. Projects from the sln are all loaded.
4. I "Run Analysis" and while running, I see this:
   [image]
5. Then I receive error:
   [image]

The Code to Analyze and Paths Referenced check out.  And there are no errors in the Analysis Error List panel:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: We just fixed a bug in the today (20Sept2018) version 2018.2.1 that could lead to this effect. Download latest version and try again https://www.ndepend.com/download

Comment: I can confirm that this version works, thanks!

Comment: Great, enjoy all ndepend capabilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install version, 2018.2.1 or later which address the bug referenced in [@Patrick from NDepend team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27194/patrick-from-ndepend-team)'s comment.

The expected behaviour is something like this while the analysis is running:
[image]

And when it finishes, the bad news looks like:
[image]

At which point the, the fire-hose of data and metrics becomes available.